# Simple algorithm for formatting 2 instances of NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two instances of NSDate objects, they represent times of start and the end of a movie file. Consider them to be

```
    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
    NSDate *endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];
```

So now I need to form an NSArray from them dividing each element as an hour from the difference in their time. To put it simpler, I, for instance, have start date

2012/02/16T22:00

and an end date

2012/02/17T03:30

Now what I would need is an array of the following objects:

```
2012/02/16 T 22:00
2012/02/16 T 23:00
2012/02/17 T 00:00
2012/02/17 T 01:00
2012/02/17 T 02:00
2012/02/17 T 03:00
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your input dates are strings like **2012/02/16T22:00** or actual NSDate objects?

Comment: The inputs are two actual NSDate objects with defined timeZone. The output type as String or Date is not important since they are easily convertible.

Comment: I don't know if I quite get it... Can't you just use a NSMutableArray and addObject method. The time between each NSDate will allways be one hour? If it is, why don't just set the startTime once and create a loop that adds 1 hour on the last NSdate and adds to the array? Or why don't you simply create a class with all the info you need and add that to the array?

Comment: @RaphaelAyres The reason is that if I simply add hours, I'll have to take dates into consideration as well, as well as verges between months, so if today date is 29 of February and it's got only 29 days, I'll have to know that to change month, day and hour. It's not so simple, but NSDate instances are working quite well when their timeZones are set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will give you an array of dates that increment by an hour.

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *date = startDate;
while ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    [dates addObject:date];
    date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:date];
}
```